# Removing part of a namespace across entire project

Tags: c#, namespaces, refactoring

I know that I can rename a namespace using Visual Studio 2010, but I need to remove part of a namespace.

```
namespace Xyz.Common.Utils { ... }
```

Renamed to

```
namespace Common.Utils { ... }
```

I need to drop the Xyz part, but don't see a way to use the VS refactoring tool to do this.

Comment: Re-sharper has, you can try the trial version

Comment: Or you can use the built-in rename function and rename it with a ridiculous/unique name and do a global replace after that.

Comment: @Silvermind that did the trick! I tried a few addons for VS but nothing worked, but that worked in the end. thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I did a few times and you don't need any third-party tool:

Refactor the name in to something unique like: `fjhfhchdbyegdrkoksodbc` (if that's unique enough to you)
Then do a global replace on `fjhfhchdbyegdrkoksodbc.` (including the dot) with an empty string.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022, year 2024: still seems to be the solution. This is about the 50th everday problem I find being not solvable in VS natively. I'm glad just having started to learn C# (coming from a Java environment). It's hard to imagine the pain VS users must have suffered 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that in pure **Visual Studio**, although there's an option when you select a word with the right button, then **Refactor »» Rename** in VS2010, this option requires you to select a symbol. In your case

```
namespace Xyz.Common.Utils { ... }
```

**Xyz** would be the symbol to refactor, but it cannot be renamed to an ***empty value***.

Telerik JustCode can do the job instead:

http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode/features.aspx

There's also a Trial Version.